# php select/selected values to be used in for automated text input in to Post title box

Tags: php, html-select

I am working on data input form. Template provided form works ok, but not in the way I need it to work.

By filling in form, visitor will select few options from dropdown boxes, like: car make, model, year, color and etc.

Then he is able to write post Title and description.

What I want to do is to not allow visitors to edit post title, but use default format by copying values from dropdown boxes depending on what selection visitor made.

1. Visitors selects car manufacturer:

   `<select name="<?php echo $dox_options['ad_set']['model']['base']; ?>" id="<?php echo $dox_options['ad_set']['model']['base']; ?>" class="<?php if ($dox_options['ad_set']['model']['required'] == 'true') echo 'required-field'; ?>"><?php dox_get_dd_terms( $dox_options['ad_set']['model']['query'], 0,0, sprintf( __('Select %s', 'autotrader'), $dox_options['ad_set']['model']['name'] ) ); ?></select>`
2. Visitors selects car model:

   `<select name="<?php echo $dox_options['ad_set']['model']['base'].'sub'; ?>" id="<?php echo $dox_options['ad_set']['model']['base'].'sub'; ?>" class="<?php if ($dox_options['ad_set']['model']['required'] == 'true') echo 'required-field'; ?>" disabled="disabled"></select>`
3. Text input for post title:

   `<input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="50" maxlength="60" class="required-field" value=""/>`

So my goal is, to do title text inserted automaticly from first two selections. Let's say visitor selected BMW as manufacturer from the first dropdown box and and X5 from the second dropdown box. When he goes to the post title are, title is already there saying BMW, X5, and title is 'readonly', so visitor does not have a chance to change it.

I'm tried all possible searches everywhere - no luck. Please HELP !!!

Comment: you need to learn how to use javascript for actively changing the page based on user interaction.

Comment: Thx. It good advise, but I need to finish this project on time and I am afraid I don't have enough time to learn java :( But I will keep searching.

Comment: in that case you will have to post the form before you can set the title.